# LINQ query not returning expected results

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am trying to join three SQL tables in LINQ c# for the below SQL

```
SELECT
    rpp.*
FROM dbo.Orgs ao
LEFT JOIN dbo.Afflia rpa
    ON rpa.AccountId = ao.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.reports rpp
    ON rpp.Id = rpa.reporttId
WHERE ao.Name like '%xyz%'
```

above query returns data but the equivalent LINQ query doesn't as in below

```
from a in context.Orgs
join aff in context.Afflia on a.ID equals aff.AccountId
join prescriber in context.Reports on aff.reportId equals prescriber.Id
where a.ORG_NAME.Contains("xyz")
```

**May I know where the mistake is?**

Comment: Are you sure this is the equivalent Linq query? I usually use the method syntax, but just by looking at it, I'd say this creates all inner joins. Can you maybe check with a profiler if they really are the same?

Comment: Because you're trying to do inner join instead of left join. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq) how to do it properly.

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names in both your SQL and LINQ queries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL you are doing a LEFT join to dbo.Afflia, but in your LINQ you are doing an inner join.  You need to add "DefaultIfEmpty(), eg

```
from aff in context.Afflia.Where(join condition here).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 2):

In LINQ you did INNER join but In SQL, you did LEFT join.

Try this instead:

```
from a in context.Orgs
join aff in context.Afflia on a.ID equals aff.AccountId into affs
from aff in affs.DefaultIfEmpty()
join prescriber in context.Reports on aff.reportId equals prescriber.Id
where a.ORG_NAME.Contains("xyz")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
        var prescribers = (from a in context.Orgs
                           from aff in context.Afflia.Where(aff => aff.AccountId == a.ID)
                           from prescriber in context.Reports.Where(pres => pres.Id == aff.reportId)
                           where a.ORG_NAME.Contains("xyz")
                           select prescriber)
                           .ToList();
```